# CloudFormation - Using Conditions, Pseudo Parameters, and Intrinsic Functions Together to define a Single Resource Property

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, elastic-load-balancer

I have a CloudFormation template that has two conditions defined. If we're launching the stack in us-west-2 (where the Network ELB **IS** supported), then it sets `CreateNetworkLoadBalancer` to True. If we're running this stack in sa-east-1 (Sao Paulo, where **only** the Classic ELB is supported), then `CreateNetworkLoadBalancer` is set to `False`, and `CreateClassicLoadBalancer` is `True`. (Example below)

```
Conditions:
  CreateClassicLoadBalancer: !Equals [ !Ref "AWS::Region", sa-east-1 ]
  CreateNetworkLoadBalancer: !Equals [ !Ref "AWS::Region", us-west-2 ]
```

The stack later defines two resources, a Network and a Classic ELB, as shown below. It spins up only the the appropriate LB, based on the region and the conditions. This all works as expected. (Example below)

```
Resources:
  ######################################################
  # Network Load Balancer, Target Group, etc.
  # NLB
  NLB:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer"
    Condition: CreateNetworkLoadBalancer
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        - Key: deletion_protection.enabled
          Value: False
      Name: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "nlb" ] ]
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets: !Ref bastionSubnetList
      Tags:
      - Key: Environment
        Value: !Ref awsTagsEnvironment
      - Key: Application
        Value: !Ref awsTagsApplication
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "nlb" ] ]
      Type: network
      IpAddressType: ipv4
  # target group
  NLBTargetGroup:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup"
    Condition: CreateNetworkLoadBalancer
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPort: 22
      HealthCheckProtocol: TCP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      Name: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "elb-target-group" ] ]
      Port: 22
      Protocol: TCP
      Tags:
      - Key: Environment
        Value: !Ref awsTagsEnvironment
      - Key: Application
        Value: !Ref awsTagsApplication
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "elb-target-group" ] ]
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: 0
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
      VpcId: !Select [0, !Ref vpcIdList]
  # Listener
  NLBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Condition: CreateNetworkLoadBalancer
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - TargetGroupArn: !Ref NLBTargetGroup
        Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref NLB
      Port: 22
      Protocol: TCP
  ######################################################


  ######################################################
  # Classic ELB - for regions that do not yet support a Network LB.
  # ELB
  ELB:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    Condition: CreateClassicLoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Subnets: !Ref bastionSubnetList
      HealthCheck:
        HealthyThreshold: '3'
        Interval: '10'
        Target: TCP:22
        Timeout: '5'
        UnhealthyThreshold: '3'
      ConnectionSettings:
        IdleTimeout: '60'
      CrossZone: 'true'
      SecurityGroups:
      - Ref: BastionELBSG
      Listeners:
      - InstancePort: '22'
        LoadBalancerPort: '22'
        Protocol: TCP
        InstanceProtocol: TCP
      LoadBalancerName: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "bastion-elb" ] ]
      Tags:
      - Key: Environment
        Value: !Ref awsTagsEnvironment
      - Key: Application
        Value: !Ref awsTagsApplication
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "bastion-elb" ] ]
```

Via a Stack Update, we now want to add code to associate the existing Load Balancer (the one that was provisioned based on the region), to an AutoScaling group. To do this, AutoScaling has separate Properties for each (`TargetGroupARNs` for Network LoadBalancer Target Groups, and `LoadBalancerNames` for Classic ELBs). We're defining both in `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup`, and relying on the True/False value of the condition, an intrinsic function (`Fn::If`), and the `AWS::NoValue` pseudo parameter. In theory the below code should work.

```
TargetGroupARNs:
        !If
          - CreateNetworkLoadBalancer
          - !Ref NLBTargetGroup
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      LoadBalancerNames:
        !If
          - CreateClassicLoadBalancer
          - !Ref ELB
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

However the syntax/format of the Yaml just isn't correct - We are getting the following error when running the stack **(Value of property TargetGroupARNs must be of type List of String)**.

What is the proper way to tie the If, the conditions, and NoValue together so that a List of a single String (resulting in either a !Ref to **NoValue** or **NLB**) is assigned to the value of `TargetGroupARNs`?

```
BastionASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZones:
        Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
      Cooldown: '0'
      DesiredCapacity: '0'
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: '60'
      HealthCheckType: EC2
      MaxSize: '0'
      MinSize: '0'
      VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref bastionSubnetList
      LaunchConfigurationName:
        Ref: BastionLC
      Tags:
      - Key: Environment
        Value: !Ref awsTagsEnvironment
        PropagateAtLaunch: true
      - Key: Application
        Value: !Ref awsTagsApplication
        PropagateAtLaunch: true
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "asg-ec2" ] ]
        PropagateAtLaunch: true
      TargetGroupARNs:
        !If
          - CreateNetworkLoadBalancer
          - !Ref NLBTargetGroup
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      LoadBalancerNames:
        !If
          - CreateClassicLoadBalancer
          - !Ref ELB
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      TerminationPolicies:
      - OldestInstance
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're better off creating two `BastionASG` resources using [conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) on the resources

```
BastionASGElb:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Condition: CreateClassicLoadBalancer
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZones:
      Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
    Cooldown: '0'
    DesiredCapacity: '0'
    HealthCheckGracePeriod: '60'
    HealthCheckType: EC2
    MaxSize: '0'
    MinSize: '0'
    VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref bastionSubnetList
    LaunchConfigurationName:
      Ref: BastionLC
    Tags:
    - Key: Environment
      Value: !Ref awsTagsEnvironment
      PropagateAtLaunch: true
    - Key: Application
      Value: !Ref awsTagsApplication
      PropagateAtLaunch: true
    - Key: Name
      Value: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "asg-ec2" ] ]
      PropagateAtLaunch: true
    LoadBalancerNames:
      - !Ref ELB
    TerminationPolicies:
    - OldestInstance

BastionASGAlb:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Condition: CreateNetworkLoadBalancer
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZones:
      Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
    Cooldown: '0'
    DesiredCapacity: '0'
    HealthCheckGracePeriod: '60'
    HealthCheckType: EC2
    MaxSize: '0'
    MinSize: '0'
    VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref bastionSubnetList
    LaunchConfigurationName:
      Ref: BastionLC
    Tags:
    - Key: Environment
      Value: !Ref awsTagsEnvironment
      PropagateAtLaunch: true
    - Key: Application
      Value: !Ref awsTagsApplication
      PropagateAtLaunch: true
    - Key: Name
      Value: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref awsTagsNamePrefix, "asg-ec2" ] ]
      PropagateAtLaunch: true
    TargetGroupARNs:  
      - !Ref NLBTargetGroup
    TerminationPolicies:
    - OldestInstance
```

Comment: Yep, that's a good way to accomplish it in another way. Thanks! Will leave this unanswered for a little longer however to see if anyone else wants to weigh-in.

Answer (score 1):

In YAML you can use two dashes `- -` to create a list of lists:

```
Prop:
  - - one
    - two
    - three
  - - red
    - blue
```

So for your `!If` statements bound to list properties you wrap the second value in a sublist:

```
TargetGroupARNs:
  !If
    - CreateNetworkLoadBalancer

    - - !Ref NLBTargetGroup

    - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Looking at my own scripts it appears the `AWS::NoValue` doesn't need to be wrapped, but if you had a different `!Ref` in the second block it would also need to be a sublist.

Comment: Great suggestion, I'll try this out and see how it goes.